# Perl create variables from substring of another variable

Tags: regex, perl

I am sure this can be done with `split()`, but I am more interested in doing it with `s//` if possible.  I want to compare a supplied IP address with an array of IP addresses and find a match if existing.  I also want to consider a partial match successful only if the entire element (not a substring of the array element) is a match.

For example: Supplied IP: 10.12.13.14

If the current array element is 10.12. or 10. or 10.12.13. We can consider that a match, but not 10.12.11.

This is to find if a given IP exists in the hosts.allow TCP wrappers file on a Linux host.  I will add functionality to append the address if it is not covered in the file.  Since Partial subnet matches like 10.120. or 192.168. work, I need to test for those as well.  That is the code I am missing below where the placeholder "OR SUBSTRING MATCHES" exists.  I want to know if `my $IP = "1.2.3.4";` how do I make substring variables so I can perform a string comparison on `"1.2.3."` and `"1.2."` ?

```
#PSEUDO CODE EXAMPLE
my @IPS = (10.12.13.14, 191.168.1.2, 10.8., 172.16. );
my $IP = "10.8.3.44";
foreach (@IPS) { if( $IP eq $_ || split(/\d+\./, 1-3, $IP) eq $_ ) { print $IP matches current IP: $_\n} 
# That split is supposed to represent "10." "10.8." and "10.8.3."  That is the logic I am trying to accomplish, but I would like to use s// if it fits the job, otherwise I am open to split() or other suggestions

#REAL CODE EXAMPLE  
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $IP = $ARGV[0];
my $FILE = '/etc/hosts.allow';

# Make sure it is an IP with either 157. or 140. as first octet

unless ( $IP =~ qr/(140|157)\.(\d{1,3}\.){2}\d{1,3}/ ) {
die "Usage: $0 IP Address" } else {
    open (FH, "<", "$FILE");
    foreach $LINE (<FH>) {
        if ( $LINE =~ qr/^sshd: (.*)/i ) {
            @LIST = split(", ", $1);
            foreach (@LIST) { 
                chomp $_;
                if($IP eq $_) || (OR SUBSTRING MATCHES ) <-need code here {
                    print "IP ADDRESS: $IP found! \n";
                } else { print "$_ is not a match\n"};
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [`Net::IP::Match::Regexp`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::IP::Match::Regexp), albeit with [some limitations](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::IP::Match::Regexp#LIMITATIONS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
if ( ($IP eq $_) || ($IP =~ /^\Q$_/) )  {
```

Comment: I am not familiar with \Q regex operator, could you explain it please?

Comment: I managed to look it up, I am on a slow connection.  It looks promising, I will test it.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working with your concept.  My problem was I had trailing whitespace in $_ that I wasn't initially aware of.  Thanks for a simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

[Why reinvent the wheel?](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aSubnet)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw/say/;
use Net::Subnet;

my $allowed_hosts = subnet_matcher qw(
    10.8.0.0/16
    10.12.13.14/32
    191.168.1.2/32 
    172.16.0.0/16
);

for my $ip (qw/10.8.3.44/) {
    if ($allowed_hosts->($ip)) {
        say "$ip is allowed!";
    }
    else {
        say "$ip is disallowed!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build a regular expression to match against your accepted list.  As M42 already demonstrated, you need to use [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) so that your period's aren't treated as the any character.  You also need to be careful about your boundary conditions as well:

```
my @ips = qw(10.12.13.14 191.168.1.2 10.8. 172.16.);
my $ips_list = join '|', map {/\d$/ ? "$_\$" : $_} map quotemeta, @ips;
my $ips_re = qr{^(?:$ips_list)};

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    if ($_ =~ $ips_re) {
        print "(pass) $_\n";
    } else {
        print "(fail) $_\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
10.8.3.44
999.10.8.999
10.12.13.14999
10.12.13.14
172.16.99.99
191.168.1.2
191.168.1.29
```

Outputs:

```
(pass) 10.8.3.44
(fail) 999.10.8.999
(fail) 10.12.13.14999
(pass) 10.12.13.14
(pass) 172.16.99.99
(pass) 191.168.1.2
(fail) 191.168.1.29
```